Sequelize query special object notation
At
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/

there is this code:
const { count, rows } = await Project.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    title: {
      [Op.like]: 'foo%'
    }
  },
  offset: 10,
  limit: 2
});
console.log(count);
console.log(rows);

In java script if a variable is declared as an object we can access that object properties in two ways:
    variable.propertyName

or
    variable["propertyName"]

(Ref:  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp )
However, sequelize uses some kind of special object notation to build queries. For example, for title:
title: {
  [Op.like]: 'foo%'
}

Is  [Op.like]   a proper object field name? is it valid to do something like
   title.[Op.like] = 'foo%'

or
title["[Op.like]"] = 'foo%'  ?

If this does not follow javascript "rules and regulations" how can this be done in Javascript?

NOTE: I will use some Python to explain the concept; no actual knowledge of Python is required, but it provides a nice contrast to JavaScript.

JavaScript property names can be strings or symbols, but let's ignore symbols for now. Normally, you can build objects with string keys like this:


obj = {
  first_name: "Jack"
}
console.log(obj)



This results in a property with the key "first_name" and the value "Jack". The key is automatically made a string. It is, in fact, equivalent to


obj = {
  "first_name": "Jack"
}
console.log(obj)



It is just that in the second form, with quotes, you can use spaces and other special characters in the string, which you obviously can't when you don't have the quotes to delimit your string.
This is in contrast to e.g. Python, where you must use the quotes; if you don't, the key would just be a variable. So, in Python, you would have to write the above as:
# Python
obj = {
  "first_name": "Jack"
}

If you omitted the quotes, Python would complain that the variable first_name was not defined.
But sometimes you want to pull the key from a variable (or more generally, an expression). For example, in Python, you can write
# Python
key = "first_name"
obj = {
    key: "Jack"
}

or
# Python
key_part = "first"
obj = {
    key_part + "_name": "Jack"
}

For the longest time, JavaScript did not have a neat way to do this. If you try to run these as JavaScript, the first one would give you { "key": "Jack" }, clearly not what we intend, and the second is a syntax error. Instead, you would have had to write:


key = "first_name"
obj = {}
obj[key] = "Jack"
console.log(obj)



However, now there is a new syntax for this "do not use the key literally as string, but evaluate the expression instead" behaviour:


key = "first_name"
obj = {
  [key]: "Jack"
}
console.log(obj)



or even


key_part = "first"
obj = {
  [key_part + "_name"]: "Jack"
}
console.log(obj)



So now there is finally parity between reading and writing properties. As you note, we can read properties with fixed string keys (obj.first_name) or with evaluated keys (obj["first_name"], obj[key], obj[key_part + "_name"]); but now we can also write object literals with fixed string keys ({ first_name: "Jack" }) and evaluated keys ({ ["first_name"]: "Jack" }, { [key]: "Jack" }, { [key_part + "_name"]: "Jack" }).
(I was purposefully omitting const in the examples above, to maintain the parallel with Python, which should highlight the differences better. However, this does not mean I endorse not declaring your constants and variables in real code :P )

Op is an object, and like is a property on it, which contains either a string or a symbol (I have not checked, but is likely a symbol). You can do console.log(Op.like), and see what is in it, if you wish. Note that evaluated keys are the only way to use a symbol as a key in an object literal, since the fixed string syntax only works for, well, strings. Op.like in your code is not a field name, but it contains a field name (whether a string or a symbol), just like key in the examples above.
To read a property, just like you can do obj[key] (or obj[key_part + "_name"]) and get "John" above, if you have an an object
const title = {
  [Op.like]: 'foo%'
}

you can access the field itself like this:
title[Op.like]

